# Numerical representation to ASCII art

Tags: java, ascii

I'm trying to write a program that will convert a numerical representation of ASCII art to the art itself.

For example,

```
3
2,+,3,*
5,-
1,+,1,-
```

Should give:

```
3
++***
-----
+-
```

The number that appears at the top of the "art" and numerical representation is the amount of lines that appear in the file.

Here is the code that I have written for this task. The file "origin.txt" contains a numerical representation of ASCII art while the destination folder should get the art itself.

```
import java.io

import java.util.*; 

public class Numerical
{
    public static void main(String[]args)

    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File input = new File("origin.txt");
        File output = new File("destination.txt");
        numToImageRep(input,output); 
    }
    public static void numToImageRep(File input, File output)

throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(input);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(output);      
       int size =     read.nextInt();                                           
        String symbol; 
        out.println(size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)                                 
    {
        int x = 0; 
        symbol = read.next();
        while(x < symbol.length())
        {
            char a = symbol.charAt(x);                           
            int c = Character.getNumericValue(a);          
            x = x + 2 ;
            char L = symbol.charAt(x);                    
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            {
                out.print(L);
            }
            x = x + 2; 
        }
        out.println(); 
    }

}

}
```

This code seems to work for a numerical format that contains no spaces, but as soon as a space appears in the numerical format, I get a string out of bounds exception.

For example:

```
2
2,+,2,*
1,+,6,-
```

will convert to art,

but,

```
2
2, ,5,*
3, ,9,*
```

Will result in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:   String index out of range: 2
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at Numerical.numToImageRep(Numerical.java:28)
at Numerical.main(Numerical.java:9)
```

I'm not sure why this could be happening. If anybody has any advice for me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: At what line do you get this error? The simple way is to simply do `if(c != 32)` that basicly only does it if c is not a space

Comment: Your code does not seem to work even for the inputs you claim it does. Check http://ideone.com/4StTgi (modified to get input from the console)

Comment: That helps, your issue is that in the while loop you check that x < symbol.zise, byut later you add two to x cause it to be larger than symbol.size

Comment: @user2693587 

I will try your suggestion and use an if statement. Thank you. 

 The reason that x increments by two is that I know the general pattern of the numerical format: I am guaranteed a number when x = 0, and am guaranteed a char when 2 is added to x. When x is greater than the size of the string, I should break out of the while loop. I only get issues when there are spaces in the file.

Comment: @shridharama 

I apologize. I did not type the numerical file correctly in my original post. I just updated my original post to the correct file.. Sorry about that. I just checked, and now it definitely works.

Comment: No problem @sadykhovful. I've answered your question now.

Answer (score 0):

Like @user2693587 said, the issue is probably with the fact that you use an x+2 while iterating over the string.

A more standard way to read your input would be to use `string.split(",")` and get an array of the characters you need numeric representations for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the statement:

```
symbol = read.next();
```

By default, the next() method of the Scanner class only returns what comes before a space. So, your when you call read.next() on the line

```
2, ,5,*
```

it returns the string "2,", which will obviously result in an out of bounds exception.

Instead, replace that line with

```
symbol = read.nextLine();
```

and it should fix your problem.